# Which is the better way (algorithm-wise) for request/search matching in a Python/MySQL system?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I’m working on a Python/MySQL match system that has:

2 million users with 2,000 unique relationships each that is recorded into a **Relationship_DB** that has about 4 billion records (2m x 2k).
Each user submit one new request every month that is entered into a **Request_DB**, that’s 24million records per year in the Request_DB. Each request is only valid for 12months so DB can be pruned on request expiry or moved to an archive.

For each new request submitted, system should return a list of matches (average 200-500matches per request) with other requests in the Request_DB categorised into various relationship type groupings.

All matches are stored in a **Match_DB** that is filtered to return the corresponding matches to users when they poll the server for updates. Match_DB size is about 10 billion records a year.

- **Relationship_DB** - UserID:Integer, Relationship_UserID:Integer,
  Relationship_Information:String Array
- **Request_DB** - UserID:Integer, Request_Parameters: String Array
- **Match_DB** - UserID:Integer, Match_UserID:Integer, Relationship
  Status:String Array

**Method 1:**

1. User submits a New Request which is immediately recorded into Request_DB.
2. Server filters all matches for the New Request from within Request_DB and SAVES ALL MATCHES into Match_DB,
3. Server then goes through each of the newly recorded matches in Match_DB, looks up Relationship_DB (read only), processes relationship data and writes the processed results for each match record in the Match_DB. This loops till all the new matches are updated.
4. When relationship results for all corresponding records in Match_DB are updated, Server returns match list from Match_DB to client (who submitted the new Request).
5. Server proceeds to update other existing Request from other users in the Match_DB that are affected by the entry of this new Request.
6. Users of the affected entries will see their updated Request results from the Match_DB when they next poll the server.

**Method 2:**

1. User submits a New Request which is immediately recorded into Request_DB.
2. Server filters all matches for the New Request from within Request_DB
3. Server goes through each of the match in the the filtered Request_DB, looks up Relationship_DB (read only), processes relationship data and writes all information as ONE new Match record in the Match_DB. This loops till all filtered match records from Request_DB has been entered into Match_DB.
4. When all match record has been processed and saved in the Match_DB, Server returns match list from Match_DB to client (who submitted the new Request).
5. Server proceeds to update other existing Request from other users in the Match_DB that are affected by the entry of this new Request.
6. Users of the affected entries will see their updated Request results from the Match_DB when they next poll the server.

For the scenario above, what are the pros and cons (on system load, speed, data integrity, etc) of the 2 methods above and the way the DB are organised, or are there better methods or suggestions? Would PHP/MySQL be a better option for the job? All queries are parametized queries.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't know that either way is more ideal than the other. In both cases you're doing a lookup on a massive DB table. That's going to be your most expensive part of any operation you do with it. I would throw as much memory at this as you can, since caching would help some.

Comment: thanks for feedback! would you suggest a different way of structuring the DBs? I thought the Request_DB structure is simple enough and not that huge a table. The problem is with the Relationship_DB at 4B records and the Match_DB at 10B records. They both contain minimal fields though.

Comment: Your best bet is a pivot table. Explicitly link the records together and, with a proper index, it shouldn't be as slow.